# Connecting to Memgraph graph database from Python

Tags: python, memgraphdb

What do I need to have in place to connect to a running instance of Memgraph from Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to Memgraph using Python you will need:

- A **running Memgraph instance**. If you need to set up Memgraph, take a look at the [Installation guide](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/installation).
- The [**GQLAlchemy client**](https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy). A Memgraph OGM (Object Graph Mapper) for the Python programming language.

Create a new Python script and add the following code to it:
from gqlalchemy import Memgraph

```
# Make a connection to the database
memgraph = Memgraph(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)

# Delete all nodes and relationships
query = "MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n"

# Execute the query
memgraph.execute(query)

# Create a node with the label FirstNode and message property with the value "Hello, World!"
query = """CREATE (n:FirstNode)
           SET n.message = '{message}'
           RETURN 'Node '  + id(n) + ': ' + n.message AS result""".format(message="Hello, World!")

# Execute the query
results = memgraph.execute_and_fetch(query)

# Print the first member
print(list(results)[0]['result'])
```

You can find detailed instructions in the [Memgraph documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/python).